# Python - shutil.copytree recursive extraction not selective

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had once tried exporting files from a storage medium to my computer using the code below. It worked. Somewhere along the way I must have altered it because instead of just recursively grabbing the files with the extention I want, it's grabbing all the files at the source.

```
def xxxlist(ext, dirname, names):
    ext = ext.lower() 
    for name in names:
        if name.lower().endswith('.xxx'): # This is the file type I need.
            print(os.path.join(dirname, name))

def xxxextract(src,dest):
        print 'Executing Extraction (may take a minute)...'
        dest_dir = os.path.dirname(dest)
        try:
            os.makedirs(dest_dir)
        except os.error as e:
            pass 
            shutil.copytree(src,dest)
        print "Successfully exported..." 
        os.path.walk(path, xxxlist, '.xxx')
```

The following is further down in the program. Calls the functions:

```
if args.extractpath:
    path = args.extractpath
        xxxextract(extractpath, 'Exports')
```

As you can see it performs an extraction then lists all those xxx files I want. But when I check the 'Exports' folder, *everything* was transferred, not just with that extension. How can I fix this to simply get it to shutil.copytree the files with the extension I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! Jon Clements told me about creating an ignore list and negating it. BlueMelon over at Dreaming in Code helped me out with crafting one:

```
def ignore_list(path, files):
   ret = []
   for fname in files:
        fullFileName = os.path.normpath(path) + os.sep + fname
   if not os.path.isdir(fullFileName) \
        and not fname.endswith('zdt'):
        ret.append(fname)
   return ret
```

This can be used with `shutil.copytree(src,dst,ignore=ignore_list)`. This is a great approach: initially tried lambda functions but wanted the exports to maintain their folder structure.